# Fourier sine and cosine transformation tool

Tags: math

I need web apllication which can give me output of fourier series, but whith sine and cosine.

Wolfram can only output with e:
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=trigonometric+Fourier+series+x%5E2

Many thanks!

Comment: `FourierTrigSeries[x^2, x, n]` on wolfram alpha